# The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm building an application using Entity Framework and C#, and in one of my tables, I noticed I named the column with the primary key the same name as the foreign key column i.e. `dbo.MembershipTypes` table's primary key is on "MembershipTypeId" property, and the `dbo.Customers` table it has a relationship with has a foreign key on "MembershipTypeId" property i.e. `public MembershipType MembershipTypeId { get; set; })`.

This caused problems, so I renamed `MembershipTypeId` back to `Id` (it was initially `Id`, but the column wasn't an identity column, and EF refused to make it one even after using `[DatabaseGenereated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and `[Key]` attributes).

I'm using code-first migrations, so when I try reverting the changes using

```
update-database -TargetMigration:(migration before mistake goes here)
```

in the package manager console, I get this error:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MembershipTypes' and the index name 'PK_dbo.MembershipTypes'. The duplicate key value is (0).
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here's the migration it gives me the error when I try to revert back to an earlier version of the database:

```
public partial class RenameIdColumnAndMakeItIdentityInMembershipTypeTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId", "dbo.MembershipTypes");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MembershipTypes");
        AddColumn("dbo.MembershipTypes", "MembershipTypeId", c => c.Byte(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.MembershipTypes", "MembershipTypeId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId", "dbo.MembershipTypes", "MembershipTypeId", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.MembershipTypes", "Id");
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.MembershipTypes", "Id", c => c.Byte(nullable: false));
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId", "dbo.MembershipTypes");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MembershipTypes");
        DropColumn("dbo.MembershipTypes", "MembershipTypeId");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.MembershipTypes", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Customers", "MembershipTypeId", "dbo.MembershipTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
}
```

Here's the T-SQL code EF used to create the table. I made the table with its properties first then populated it with the reference data in a separate migration.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MembershipTypes] 
(
    [SignUpFee]        SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
    [DurationInMonths] TINYINT       NOT NULL,
    [DiscountRate]     TINYINT       NOT NULL,
    [Name]             NVARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    [MembershipTypeId] TINYINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.MembershipTypes] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MembershipTypeId] ASC)
);
```

Here's the code used to generate the Customers table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] 
(
    [Id]                       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                     NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [IsSubscribedToNewsletter] BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [MembershipTypeId]         TINYINT        DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Birthdate]                DATETIME       NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Customers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.MembershipTypes_MembershipTypeId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MembershipTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MembershipTypes] ([MembershipTypeId]) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MembershipTypeId]
ON [dbo].[Customers]([MembershipTypeId] ASC);
```

This all came about as I was trying to fix the API to create a new customer using `[HttpPost]`.

Please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it. Also, kindly help me understand why the duplicate key starts at 0 and not 1.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: In the `Down` method `Id` is not an identity column.

Comment: Thank you, @GertArnold! That was the issue. 

After making the `Id` column an identity column in the `Down` method, everything worked as intended. Simple mistake, but I learned quite a bit trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **Gert Arnold** for answering this one in the comments.

The reason I was getting this error is that the `Id` column in the `Down` method of my migration was not an identity column.

My understanding is that since the `Id` column, which often has the primary key in a relational database, cannot be null, 0 is inserted there because this is the default value for a byte or integer types.

In my `Up` method, I made `Id` an identity column, but since the default value of 0 was already present, this created a conflict because the database is now generating a value for `Id` starting with 0.

This can't work because an `Id` column is unique and can't have duplicate values. Even if, for example, you had 5 customers in your database and deleted customer 4, no other customer will have an Id of 4.

Hope this helps someone in the future!